# What is the expected length of the implied side and area formed by bending a unit length at a random point and angle?

Tags: trigonometry, uniform-distribution, geometric-probability

**What is the length of the length of the implied side and area of a triangle created by bending a unit length at a uniformly distributed point and angle?** By simulation it seems that the expected length of the implied side is somewhere around .785 and I think is determined exactly by the law of cosines and the following integral. But if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466154/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-hypotenuse-formed-by-bending-a-unit-length-ra) special case was beyond my integration skills, this integral definitely is...

$$\int_{\theta=0}^\pi \int_{x=0}^1 \sqrt{x^2+(1-x)^2+2 x(1-x) cos\theta} dx d\theta$$

Again bonus points for determining the expected area of the implied triangle!

Comment: Technically, a side of a triangle is not a hypotenuse unless the angle opposite it is right.

Comment: @JosephCamacho Yes good point, edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected area is not too messy to compute. Let $x \in [0,1]$ and $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ be chosen uniformly at random. The "infinitesimal probability" of any particular scenario is $dx \cdot d\theta/\pi$. We then construct a triangle with sides $x$, $1-x$ and angle $\theta$ between them; the area of the triangle in this scenario is $$\frac{1}{2} x(1-x) \sin(\theta)$$ and hence the average area is $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2} x(1-x) \sin(\theta) \, dx \, \frac{d\theta}{\pi} = \frac{1}{6\pi}$$

The integral computing the expected length of the third side is rather messy. We will need to write things in terms of the *complete elliptic integral of the second kind*, which for our purposes I'll define as $$E(m) := \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-m\sin^2 (\theta)} \, d\theta$$ For any $a>b$, we then have (using the half-angle formula $\cos(\theta) = 1 - 2\sin^2 (\theta/2)$) that $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{a-b\cos(\theta)} \, d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{a-b + 2b \sin^2 (\theta/2)} \, d\theta $$ $$= 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{a-b + 2b \sin^2 (\theta)} \, d\theta = 2\sqrt{a-b} E\left(\frac{2b}{b-a} \right)$$ Using this calculation, we now have that our expected length equals $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{x^2 + (1-x)^2 - 2x(1-x) \cos(\theta)} \, \frac{d\theta}{\pi} \, dx $$ $$= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} |1-2x|E\left(\frac{-4x(1-x)}{(1-2x)^2} \right) \, dx $$ Now, apparently the function $E(m)$ satisfies what is called the *imaginary modulus identity* $$E(-m) = \sqrt{1+m}\cdot  E\left(\frac{m}{1+m} \right)$$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61300/identity-for-complete-elliptic-integral-of-the-second-kind) for a reference). Using this identity, we compute that for $x\in [0,1]$, we have $$|1-2x|E\left(\frac{-4x(1-x)}{(1-2x)^2} \right) = E(4x(1-x))$$ so our integral nicely simplifies to $$\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} E(4x(1-x)) \, dx$$  Now, citing this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind), we have the following series expansion: $$E(m) = \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n}\right)^2 \frac{m^n}{1-2n}$$ Thus, integrating through the summation, we find $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1} E(4x(1-x))\, dx $$ $$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n}\right)^2 \frac{4^n}{1-2n} \int_{0}^{1} x^n (1-x)^n \, dx$$ Using properties of the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), we know that $$\int_{0}^{1} x^n (1-x)^n \, dx = \frac{1}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n} }$$ and thus the sum simplifies to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{(1-2n)(2n+1)} $$ $$= 1- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} =: 1-S$$ We now wish to compute $S$, which we will do by first writing $$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} $$ $$= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} \left(\frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n} (2n-1)} \binom{2n}{n} -   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n} (2n+1)} \binom{2n}{n}\right)$$ where we can split the sums like this since they each converge absolutely. It is well known that $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$ and hence we have $$\frac{f(x^2) - 1}{x^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} x^{2n-2} $$ $$\implies \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{f(x^2) - 1}{x^2} \, dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{2^{2n} (2n-1)}$$ and similarly $$f(x^2) - 1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} x^{2n} $$ $$\implies 2\int_{0}^{1/2} f(x^2) - 1 \, dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{2^{2n} (2n+1)}$$ It follows that $S$ equals the integral $$\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{f(x^2) - 1}{x^2} \, dx  - 2\int_{0}^{1/2} f(x^2) - 1 \, dx  \right) = \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{(1-4x^2)^{1/2} - (1-4x^2)}{4x^2} \, dx$$ It is reasonably straightforward to calculate this integral explicitly using "calculus 2" techniques (the integrand has an elementary antiderivative) and one finds $S = 1- \pi/4$ so that, at last, the answer is the remarkable closed form expression $1-S = \boxed{\pi/4}$.

Comment: Why is that $\pi/4$ to six decimal places ?

Comment: Probably it equals $\pi/4$! I'll see if I can show this.

Comment: Update: there you have it!

Comment: Tremendous effort